# Why isn't Pearson correlation coefficient used as a test statistic for hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, pearson-r

For testing the significance of Pearson correlation coefficient the following statistic is calculated then t-distribution is used.

$$\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$

Isn't it possible to calculate a probability distribution for Pearson correlation coefficient directly and then use it for hypothesis testing?

Comment: Yes, and this has been done.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_exact_distribution for instance.  The distribution depends on the null hypothesis, though, indicating your question needs a little more focus.

Comment: @whuber I've in mind the null hypothesis that the correlation is zero.

Comment: Sure--but the null distribution still depends on the underlying model.  It will be different for a bivariate Normal distribution and a bivariate Gamma distribution, for instance.

Comment: @whuber I see, I've in mind bivariate Normal distribution.